# How to stop an actionListener from executing its code if the user chooses no on a confirm dialog box?

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

I have an actionListener set up on a button. If the user clicks it it adds 10 to a progress bar. I want to allow the user to cancel their button press and prevent the code within the actionListener from executing. I.e. i want my program to just disregard the users click if they choose no on a confirm dialog box.

Is a try/catch exception the way to go here?

Thanks.

```
btnFightCrime.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            if (JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "This action will cost you 5 energy points, and you'll gain 5 action points.", "Proceed?",
                    JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION) == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {
                // yes option
            } else if (JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION==JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {

            btnFightCrime.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){   
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                    Crimes.randomCrime();
                    fightCrime(iActionBar);
                    Random r = new Random();
                    int delay = 0;
                    //delay is * 1000 because the format for timers is milliseconds
                    timer = new Timer ((delay*0), new ActionListener(){
                        @Override
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0){
                            btnFightCrime.setVisible(true);
                            btnIgnore.setVisible(true);
                            lblVillainCrime.setVisible(false);
                            lblHeroCrime.setVisible(true);

                            frame.validate();
                            timer.stop();
                        }   
    });
                    timer.start();
                    btnFightCrime.setVisible(false);
                    btnIgnore.setVisible(false);
                    lblHeroCrime.setVisible(false);
                    frame.validate();
                    }
            });
            }
                }
            });


if (JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "This action will cost you 5 energy points, and you'll gain 5 action points.", "Proceed?",
                    JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION) == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                btnFightCrime.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){   
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                        Crimes.randomCrime();
                        fightCrime(iActionBar);
                        Random r = new Random();
                        int delay = 0;
                        //delay is * 1000 because the format for timers is milliseconds
                        timer = new Timer ((delay*0), new ActionListener(){
                            @Override
                            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0){
                                btnFightCrime.setVisible(true);
                                btnIgnore.setVisible(true);
                                lblVillainCrime.setVisible(false);
                                lblHeroCrime.setVisible(true);

                                frame.validate();
                                timer.stop();
                            }   
        });
                        timer.start();
                        btnFightCrime.setVisible(false);
                        btnIgnore.setVisible(false);
                        lblHeroCrime.setVisible(false);
                        frame.validate();
                        }
                });
            } else if (JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION==JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {


            }
```

Comment: Do you mean putting the action listener within an if statement? would that actually work?

Comment: Since I have no working example from which to deduce context, I have no real idea what relationship your confirmation dialog has with your `ActionListener`, but if you are asking the user within the `ActionListener`, you could simply use an `if` statement to determine what action the user wants...

Comment: I just added the code. My program is too large to include everything, I hope that's enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use an `if` statement and check the return state of the confirmation dialog...

```
int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this, "Are you sure you want to destory the world?", "Destory World", JOptionPane.YES_OPTION);
if (result == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
    // Blow it up
}
```

Of course, you could use the same technique, but use flag, so if the confirmation process is separate from the update process, but then it becomes more difficult

**Based on updated code**

I'm going to take a stab in the dark and "guess" this is what you really mean...

```
btnFightCrime.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        if (JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "This action will cost you 5 energy points, and you'll gain 5 action points.", "Proceed?",
                        JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION) == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
            Crimes.randomCrime();
            fightCrime(iActionBar);
            Random r = new Random();
            int delay = 0;
            //delay is * 1000 because the format for timers is milliseconds
            timer = new Timer((delay * 0), new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    btnFightCrime.setVisible(true);
                    btnIgnore.setVisible(true);
                    lblVillainCrime.setVisible(false);
                    lblHeroCrime.setVisible(true);

                    frame.validate();
                    timer.stop();
                }
            });
            timer.start();
            btnFightCrime.setVisible(false);
            btnIgnore.setVisible(false);
            lblHeroCrime.setVisible(false);
            frame.validate();

        }
    }
};
```

There is no point in doing `} else if (JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION==JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {`, this will (most likely) always be `false` (or at least, be completely unreliable).

Adding ANOTHER `ActionListener` inside the `ActionListener` for the same button doesn't make any sense.  Simply ask the user, "do you wan to do this?", if the answer "Yes", do, otherwise, don't, they've already clicked the button...

Comment: When I put the action listener and all the code within the an if else statement the confirm dialog opens before my main program and then it doesn't function at all when I click on the button.

Comment: @Connor But that's not what I suggested you do, I suggested that you change the outer `ActionListener` itself (attached to the `btnFightCrime`)